# How to assign value to the variable @ Title of a sharepoint form

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom form, which I have removed the Employee field, which would take the variable @ Title of SharePoint and I want the value of the user making the form to that variable.

Someone could explain how to assign that value to the variable @ Title, I have days looking for information and can not find anything right.

Answer (score 0):

Title is a text field whereas "the value of the user making the form" would be an SPUser field, at least OOB. There is already a field in all SP lists called "Created By" (called internally by the name "Author") which saves the name of the person who originally created the list item.

If what you want is the user name in the "Title" field as well, you could pull it thusly:

```
SPUser user = (SPUser)spListItem["Author"];
spListItem["Title"] = user.Name;
```

If you want the entire SPUser object, just use the Author field.